# WebRequest / CSRF - Instagram Login

Tags: c#, http, https, request

#### **Problem**

I would like to receive login requests to the Instagram server with post/login requests with **CSRF** token or without
(if possible).

I don't want to use **selenium**, the execution of the login to the **Instagram** server should be done **programmatically**.

#### **Question**

What should I change in the source code to be able to login into instagram with **CSRF** token or without (if possible)

---

**Source Code** - Class: **Program.cs**

```
using System;


namespace WebRequests
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Net.CookieContainer myCookies = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
            string myStr = HttpMethods.Get("http://localhost/dvwapp/login.php", "http://localhost/dvwapp/login.php", ref myCookies);
            string token;
            Console.WriteLine("Token: " + (token = GetBetween(myStr, "name='user_token' value='", "' />")));

            Console.Write("Username: ");
            string username = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Password: ");
            string password = Console.ReadLine();

            string postData = "username=" + username + "&password=" + password + "&Login=Login&user_token=" + token;

            bool result = HttpMethods.Post("http://localhost/dvwapp/login.php", postData, "http://localhost/dvwapp/login.php", myCookies);
            Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static string GetBetween(string message, string start, string end)
        {
            int startIndex = message.IndexOf(start) + start.Length;
            int stopIndex = message.IndexOf(end);
            return message.Substring(startIndex, stopIndex - startIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

**Source Code** - Class: **HttpMethods.cs**

```
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

namespace WebRequests
{
  public class HttpMethods
    {

        public static string Get(string url, string referer, ref CookieContainer cookies)
        {
            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            req.Method = "GET";
            req.CookieContainer = cookies;
            req.UserAgent = "";
            req.Referer = referer;

            HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
            cookies.Add(resp.Cookies);

            string pageSrc;
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                pageSrc = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
            return pageSrc;
        }

        public static bool Post(string url, string postData, string referer, CookieContainer cookies)
        {
            string key = "Login failed";

            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            req.Method = "POST";
            req.CookieContainer = cookies;
            req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36";
            req.Referer = referer;
            req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            req.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8";

            Stream postStream = req.GetRequestStream();
            byte[] postBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
            postStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
            postStream.Dispose();

            HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
            cookies.Add(resp.Cookies);

            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
            string pageSrc = sr.ReadToEnd();
            sr.Dispose();
            //Console.WriteLine(pageSrc);
            return (!pageSrc.Contains(key));
        }
    }
}
```